# If one cell with data and a linked cell to the one has no data, then show a message

Tags: vba, excel

The images attached here show what am looking for, first image with blue boundary is where the code works as it should be, then if exists an empty cell (marked on red boundary) didn't show the next names signposted at G column and needed to be shown on the window message warning (shown on second image).

Column G need to be checked if there are names first, then check in the same row at column F if data is entered, if not, then show a message like the second image.

[image]

Window warning the names without data, signposted at the end missed names.

[image]

Actual code used:

```css
        Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
 Dim row As Integer
 Dim itemList As String

 Set dataSheet = Sheets("Datos del Proyecto")

  row = 7

  Do While dataSheet.Range("G" & row) <> 0

    If dataSheet.Range("F" & row) = 0 Then

        If itemList <> "" Then
            itemList = itemList & vbNewLine
        End If
        Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Datos del Proyecto").Range("F5:F70")
        itemList = itemList & "- " & dataSheet.Range("G" & row) & ", en la fila " & row & "."

    End If

    row = row + 1

Loop

If itemList <> "" Then

    Call MsgBox("Ingresar el salarios de:" & vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & itemList, vbInformation, "CUBIMSA")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Do While dataSheet.Range("G" & row) <> 0` this causes the loop to terminate if it finds an empty cell. Look up how to use `Range.End(xlUp)` to find the last used row of a column and use a `For` or `For Each` loop.

Comment: Set `lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).row` and check condition for row<=lastrow

Comment: Excuse me, but I has no success using the Range.End(xlUp) or row<=lastrow 
Can you give me one last help please?